# D3.js attrTween Returning Null (Unexpected Behavior)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a very basic D3 SVG which essentially consists of a couple arcs.

No matter what I use (attr, attrTween, and call) I cannot seem to get the datum via the first argument of the callback--it is always coming back null (I presume it's some kind of parse error, even though the path renders correctly?)

I might be overlooking something basic as I am relatively new to the library...

```
var el      = $('#graph'),
                        width   = 280,
                        height  = 280,
                        twoPi   = Math.PI * 2,
                        total   = 0;

                    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .startAngle(0)
                        .innerRadius(110)
                        .outerRadius(130),

                        svg = d3.select('#graph').append("svg")
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"),

                        meter = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'progress');

                    /* Add Meter Background */

                    meter.append('path')
                        .attr('class', 'background')
                        .attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi))
                        .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)');

                    /* Add in Icon */

                    meter.append('text')
                        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                        .attr('class', 'fa fa-user')
                        .attr('y',30)
                        .text('')


                    /* Create Meter Progress */

                    var percentage  = 0.4,
                        foreground  = meter.append('path').attr('class', 'foreground')
                                        .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
                                        .attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi*percentage)),

                        setAngle    = function(transition, newAngle) {

                            transition.attrTween('d',     function(d,v,i) {
console.log(d,v,i)
                            });
                            /*transition.attrTween('d', function(d) { console.log(this)
                                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
                                return function(t) { d.endAngle = interpolate(t); return arc(d); };
                            });*/

                        };


                    setTimeout(function() {
                        percentage = 0.8;
                        foreground.transition().call(setAngle, percentage*twoPi);
                    },2000);
```

It's this block of code that seems to be problematic:

```
transition.attrTween('d', function(d,v,i) {
    console.log(d,v,i)
});
```

Returning:

```
undefined 0 "M7.959941299845452e-15,-130A130,130 0 0,1 76.4120827980215,105.17220926874317L64.65637775217205,88.99186938124421A110,110 0 0,0 6.735334946023075e-15,-110Z"
```

I tried using the interpolator to parse the i value as a string since I cannot seem to acquire "d," however that had a parsing error returning a d attribute with multiple NaN.

This all seems very strange seeing as it's a simple path calculated from an arc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of basically all callbacks in D3 (`d` here) is the data element that is bound to the DOM element you're operating on. In your case, no data is bound to anything and therefore `d` is undefined.

I've updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/529kP/1/) to animate the transition and be more like the pie chart examples. The percentage to show is bound to the path as the datum. Then all you need to do is bind new data and create the tween in the same way as for any of the pie chart examples:

```
meter.select("path.foreground").datum(percentage)
     .transition().delay(2000).duration(750)
     .attrTween('d', function(d) {
       var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
       this._current = interpolate(0);
       return function(t) {
         return arc.endAngle(twoPi*interpolate(t))();
       };
});
```

Comment: Sorry for being a bit daft but despite the documentation and tutorials I can't seem to get a grasp on the best way to do this...  I'm assuming I should use something such as `scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,twoPi])` but when it comes to actually binding the data, how would this be done in a simple arc animation context?  Not opposed to a little light reading if there is critical background I need to understand...

Comment: Well, what are you actually trying to do? If you want to do a pie chart, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

Comment: Well, I dove in working off of this (almost exactly what I want, although I want to define the endAngle statically and not have it be based on a progress callback) [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941)... For some reason I don't see the data method used explicitly there at all (only setting the path d attribute), although I'm guessing it's somewhere in the progress listener?

Comment: I also realize that may be old however as I believe the tween method was deprecated as of v3?

Comment: Just noting, adding `.datum({ endAngle: twoPi*percentage })` to the foreground arc resolves the `d undefined` error, however there is still no animation?

Comment: It looks like your transition isn't attached to anything (you haven't included its definition). Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle to be more like the pie chart example. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you!!  Solution looks perfect.  If I want to learn more about the d3 best practices and design patterns is there somewhere better you recommend or should I keep digging through the examples?

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular document on this, but the examples and especially tutorials are certainly a good place to start.